# python3 読み込み時間について

Tags: python, python3

下記を読み込む時間は20秒以上かかる場合離脱するようにしています。

```
r = requests.get(url, timeout=20)
```

ただ下記のようにBFで読み込む場合ずっと読み込む状態のとき離脱する方法がわかりません。

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "html.parser")
```

解決方法を教えていただければ幸いです。

Comment: try-exceptionで囲むだけじゃダメですか？

Comment: 直接の回答ではありませんが、`BeautifulSoup` の第一引数は `r.content` 又は `r.text` ではなくてよろしいのでしょうか？